# How to update a model instance in another model save method in django?

Tags: python, django

I have a master model which creates alphanumeric automatically for different types of Vouchers for different companies. How do I update the master model.
The models:

```
class VoucherTypeMaster(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=12,null=True,blank=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=30,null=True,blank=True)
    last_number = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company,
                                   related_name='voucher_master_company')
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('code','company')

class Voucher(models.Model):
    type = models.ForeignKey(VoucherTypeMaster)
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.datetime.now().date())
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company,
                                  related_name='voucher_company')
    number = models.CharField(max_length=20,null=True,blank=True)
    narration = models.CharField(max_length=30,null=True,blank=True)
    amount = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=9)

    # class Meta:
        # unique_together = ('company','number','date')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s - %s' %(self.number,self.narration)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            voucher_type = VoucherTypeMaster.objects.get(
                company=self.company,
                code=self.type.code
                )
            voucher_type.last_number += 1
            voucher_type.save()
            self.number = voucher_type.last_number
#            self.type.save() # throws exception
        except Exception,e:
            print e

        super(Voucher, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

If I uncomment self.type.save()  Traceback  got:

> Manager isn't accessible via VoucherTypeMaster instances

How to update the VoucherTypeMaster model with the next value?  Using django 1.6.5, linux

Comment: If you uncomment `self.type.save()`, what you get is not a traceback but just the exception message. Do yourself (and the world) a favour and *get rid of that harmful useless except clause* - it only prevents you from getting relevant informations about your exception...

Now for your error: *why* do you want to call `self.type.save()`  (when you didn't even changed `self.type` - unless ` self.type` is supposed to be the same as  what you get from `VoucherTypeMaster.objects.get()` but then what's the point when you already have a foreign key on `VoucherTypeMaster` ?

Comment: Did you consider model inheritance of Voucher to VoucherTypeMaster, that may make your code DRYer and less cumbersome.

Comment: also what happens when two requests happen at the same time? incrementing last_number isn't atomic?

Comment: How will inheritance help in this case can u plz elaborate

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/594589/dm03514 can you please suggest a better way to achieve this?Desperate

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Overriding the save method on Voucher model and passing the VoucherTypeMaster and not its instance solved the problem:
Increment the last_number, if the self.id is None

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        voucher_type = VoucherTypeMaster.objects.get(
            company=self.company,
            code=self.type.code
            )
        if self.id is None:
            voucher_type.last_number = voucher_type.last_number+1
            self.type = voucher_type
            voucher_type.save()
    except Exception,e:
        print e
    super(Voucher, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```